# Developing Real Estate website for client but can't find IDX solution

Tags: wordpress, integration, listings, rets, datafeed

I had a real estate client that did a redesign of his website. On his previous website his listings were presented through IDX/MlS. My client has an MLS account and we have access to the IDX/RETS data feed. Every solution I find costs a good amount of money. When I spoke to my client about this he said on his previous website he wasn't paying anything for the listings to show. He wasn't happy thinking he was going to spend money. So my question is how can i get the listings to show on his new wordpress website I developed in a cost effective method. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make it more clear? Are you asking, still that client have the access to the rets feed and you are asking how to list those in your wordpress site?

Comment: No I got the permission to the RETS datafeed. I am trying to list my client's MLS listings on the new wordpress website in a cost effective method. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Why can't you use a rets client say PHRETS to get the mls listing and list out in wordpress site.

Comment: I'm not too tech savy on that. Can you explain a little more @SanjayKumarNS Thanks.

Comment: Get the phrets library from here: https://github.com/dangodev/PHRETS-Example/blob/master/lib/phrets.php
and fetch the real estate data using this lib and pass it to your wordpress site.

Comment: @KaushalKakadia you can use our iframe solution, checkout http://www.rewidx.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a rets data feed, you need to use a library like phRETS to connect to the MLS and download all the listing data. You'll then parse the raw data into your own database. From there you can query your database for the listings.

Then you'll need to download/parse the newest and updated listings everyday.

Listing photos work exactly the same way (you download, store and display).

If you are not that advanced in programming, your going to need to use a 3rd party idx provider. Find one that makes a wordpress plug in specifically.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Cost effective is relative isn't it? Development cost for a solution can be high.  As well as maintenance cost on FTP/IDX/Database solution.

If he had a free solution, it was probably an iframe solution from his MLS.  But that loses the SEO juice and doesn't actually show content from his site but redirects it away.

Might not be what you are looking for but some opt for software as a service solutions to take care of this, as to not have to pay for the upfront development (integrating with RETS can be difficult to start from scratch).

There are several RETS plugins for wordpress.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=RETS

One was developed around one of our SaaS solution as well.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/getrets/